# NC364T nic lots of drop when traffic hit 250kpps rate

Tags: linux, performance, ethernet

I have Server with 32 core CPU and it has `NC364T` Quad 1G ethernet and i have notice when packet rate hit `250kpps` (200,000 packet per second) i start seeing intermediate drops in `ifconfig` output and in my system `ksoftirqd/0` process start eating CPU because it stick to single `CPU0` instead of spread load across all CPU.

```
[root@server1 ~]# ifconfig | grep drop
        RX errors 0  dropped 3019497  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

This is what i did try to resolve issue.

1. increase RX ring buffer size to max `4096`

   `ethtool -G enp9s0f0 rx 4096`
2. Try to adjust affinity but still no luck

   `cat "ff" > /proc/irq/86/smp_affinity`

But still i am seeing drops, here is the some output

```
[root@server1 ~]# ethtool -S enp9s0f0 | grep rx
     rx_packets: 21351639073
     rx_bytes: 2150885430317
     rx_broadcast: 3520806
     rx_multicast: 1054
     rx_errors: 0
     rx_length_errors: 0
     rx_over_errors: 0
     rx_crc_errors: 0
     rx_frame_errors: 0
     rx_no_buffer_count: 49483446
     rx_missed_errors: 2997479
     rx_long_length_errors: 0
     rx_short_length_errors: 0
     rx_align_errors: 0
     rx_flow_control_xon: 0
     rx_flow_control_xoff: 0
     rx_csum_offload_good: 21089322623
     rx_csum_offload_errors: 107538
     rx_header_split: 0
     alloc_rx_buff_failed: 0
     rx_smbus: 0
     rx_dma_failed: 0
     rx_hwtstamp_cleared: 0
```

details setting

```
[root@server1 ~]# ethtool -k enp9s0f0
Features for enp9s0f0:
rx-checksumming: on
tx-checksumming: on
    tx-checksum-ipv4: off [fixed]
    tx-checksum-ip-generic: on
    tx-checksum-ipv6: off [fixed]
    tx-checksum-fcoe-crc: off [fixed]
    tx-checksum-sctp: off [fixed]
scatter-gather: on
    tx-scatter-gather: on
    tx-scatter-gather-fraglist: off [fixed]
tcp-segmentation-offload: on
    tx-tcp-segmentation: on
    tx-tcp-ecn-segmentation: off [fixed]
    tx-tcp6-segmentation: on
udp-fragmentation-offload: off [fixed]
generic-segmentation-offload: on
generic-receive-offload: on
large-receive-offload: off [fixed]
rx-vlan-offload: on
tx-vlan-offload: on
ntuple-filters: off [fixed]
receive-hashing: on
highdma: on [fixed]
rx-vlan-filter: on [fixed]
vlan-challenged: off [fixed]
tx-lockless: off [fixed]
netns-local: off [fixed]
tx-gso-robust: off [fixed]
tx-fcoe-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-gre-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-ipip-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-sit-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-udp_tnl-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-mpls-segmentation: off [fixed]
fcoe-mtu: off [fixed]
tx-nocache-copy: off
loopback: off [fixed]
rx-fcs: off
rx-all: off
tx-vlan-stag-hw-insert: off [fixed]
rx-vlan-stag-hw-parse: off [fixed]
rx-vlan-stag-filter: off [fixed]
busy-poll: off [fixed]
tx-sctp-segmentation: off [fixed]
l2-fwd-offload: off [fixed]
hw-tc-offload: off [fixed]
```

Nic details

```
[root@server1 ~]# lspci | grep -i eth
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) (rev 06)
09:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) (rev 06)
0a:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) (rev 06)
0a:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) (rev 06)
```

It does support `MSI` too `lspci -vv` but it doesn't have `MSI-X`

```
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) (rev 06)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company NC364T PCI Express Quad Port Gigabit Server Adapter
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr+ Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
        Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 86
        NUMA node: 0
        Region 0: Memory at f7de0000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
        Region 1: Memory at f7d00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
        Region 2: I/O ports at 6000 [size=32]
        Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 2
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI+ D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
                Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=1 PME-
        Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
                Address: 00000000fee00c18  Data: 0000
        Capabilities: [e0] Express (v1) Endpoint, MSI 00
                DevCap: MaxPayload 256 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <64us
                        ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE- FLReset- SlotPowerLimit 0.000W
                DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable+ Non-Fatal+ Fatal+ Unsupported+
                        RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+
                        MaxPayload 256 bytes, MaxReadReq 4096 bytes
                DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr+ FatalErr- UnsuppReq+ AuxPwr+ TransPend-
                LnkCap: Port #2, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x4, ASPM L0s, Exit Latency L0s <4us, L1 <64us
                        ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp-
                LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
                        ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
                LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x4, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
                UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq+ ACSViol-
                UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq+ ACSViol-
                UESvrt: DLP+ SDES- TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
                CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr-
                CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr-
                AERCap: First Error Pointer: 14, GenCap- CGenEn- ChkCap- ChkEn-
        Capabilities: [140 v1] Device Serial Number 00-26-55-ff-ff-d2-1a-6c
        Kernel driver in use: e1000e
        Kernel modules: e1000e
```

Comment: Has that network a lot of Windows machines and/or a lot of broadcasts/multicasts?  Are you using jumbo frames where you shouldnt? The NIC is only one part of the equation.

Comment: No i am not using `jumbo` frame, its and no other custom setting i did, i am running CentOS7, but or most of traffic is `UDP` streaming, if packet rate is low under 200kpps everything works but when it go high i noticing drops

Comment: Are you sure it is 200kbps? It seems too low for that kind of problems.

Comment: I am saying `200,000` packet per second arrival rate of packets not a size of packet, my traffic is `200Mbps`   don't get confused in `kbps` it is `kpps`